# Transitive relation between random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Prove that for all random variables X, Y, Z, whenever $X\stackrel{a.s.}{=}Y$ and $Y\stackrel{a.s.}{=}Z$, then $X\stackrel{a.s.}{=}Z$

**Thoughts** From definition I know that $\mathbb{P}\left(X=Y\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Y=Z\right)=1$.

I think that $\left(X=Y\mid Y=Z\right)=\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)=Y\left(\omega\right)\right\} \cap\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid Y\left(\omega\right)=Z\left(\omega\right)\right\}$.

and from that I can easily say this intersection equal $\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)=Z\left(\omega\right)\right\}=\mathbb{P}\left(X=Z\right)$.

not sure if it's even help but it worth a try.

Comment: Yes, that approach works.  From there, you just need that if $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(B) = 1$ then $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = 1$.  That has probably already been proven, but is not too hard to show if not.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection $\{X=Y\}\cap\{Y=Z\}$ is not *equal* to $\{X=Z\}$. The best you can say is
$$\{X=Y\}\cap\{Y=Z\}\subset\{X=Z\},$$ and therefore $P(X=Z)\ge P(\{X=Y\}\cap\{Y=Z\}).$ However, the desired conclusion follows, since $P(\{X=Y\}\cap\{Y=Z\})=1$ (why?) and $P(X=Z)\le 1$.